# windows 10: process 1 output used as process 2 input: pipes

Tags: windows, process, pipe, screen-recorder, adb

process 1 :
`adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 6000000 --size 1280x720 --output-format=h264 -`

process 2:
`ffplay -f h264`

normally ffplay takes its input as an argument (`-i _input`)

**How to pipe those processes ? The output of process 1 must be the input of process 2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The output of process 1 must be the input of process 2

```
adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 6000000 --size 1280x720 --output-format=h264 - | ffplay -f h264 -
```

Note the additional `-` at the end of the `ffplay` command.

Source: See answers to this question [Use adb screenrecord command to mirror Android screen to PC via USB - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472962/use-adb-screenrecord-command-to-mirror-android-screen-to-pc-via-usb)

Comment: Thank you. But what is the purpose of the additional `-` at the end of adb command and ffplay command ?

Comment: I've no idea :/